# How to put a rule after font-changed paragraph, without extra vertical space

Tags: spacing, formatting

I'm working on a template for a conference paper. It's a two-column article, with a copyright statement at the top of the initial column, followed by a horizontal rule immediately underneath. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,twoside,10pt]{article}
\title{Some sort of title}
\author{My name}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

{\scriptsize
 Copyright 2018, held by some organization with a long name that will 
 invariably break over a single line.\hfill\break
 This paper was prepared for presentation at the foo
 59\textsuperscript{th} Annual Bar Baz Symposium held in London, UK, June
 20-26, 2018.\par}\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\section{Abstract}

More text that says something useful.

\end{document}
```

Without the `\par` in the smaller-script block, there is far too much spacing between lines in the copyright block. With the `\par`, there's an extra line's worth of spacing beneath the copyright text and the rule.

[image: Too much vertical space between copyright text and the horizontal rule]

Presumably I should be able to override the spacing after a paragraph in the copyright block, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Does using `\vspace{some value}` before and/or after the copyright notice help? "Some value" could be positive or negative, a few pt, and does not need to be integer.

Comment: You can replace the last line by `20-26, 2018.\\\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}\par}`. Although some people might want to see me scream in pain because of this :P

Comment: Welcome to here. Some value could be `-\parskip`? @RobtAll

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It is one thing to practise evil; it is another thing to commend it to others. In any case, that still adds vertical space, even if not 'extra' vertical space. And it is Bad, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,twoside,10pt]{article}
\title{Some sort of title}
\author{My name}
\date{}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

{\scriptsize
 Copyright 2018, held by some organization with a long name that will 
 invariably break over a single line.\hfill\break
 This paper was prepared for presentation at the foo
 59\textsuperscript{th} Annual Bar Baz Symposium held in London, UK, June
 20-26, 2018.\par}\vspace*{-.75\baselineskip}\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\section{Abstract}

More text that says something useful.

\end{document}
```

[image: undo vertical skip]

Comment: To really undo all the vertical space, delete the `.75`. However, you probably don't want to do *that* as it will put the line on the baseline of the last line of the copyright notice.

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,twoside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\title{Some sort of title}
\author{My name}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\scriptsize\arraybackslash}X@{}}%\scriptsize
 Copyright 2018, held by some organization with a long name that will
 invariably break over a single line. \\%%\hfill\break
 This paper was prepared for presentation at the foo
 59\textsuperscript{th} Annual Bar Baz Symposium held in London, UK, June
 20-26, 2018.\\
 \midrule
 \end{tabularx}%

\section{Abstract}

More text that says something useful.

\end{document}
```

[image]